# can not insert to database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, if-statement

i want to check when insert unit_id we must check unit_id alraedy used to another fleet or not. when already used show message error and not used another fleet unit_id can insert to database.

this is code in controller

```
    function add_fleet_member()
    {
        $this->data['unit_list']= $this->munit_list->get_all_unit_list2();
        $this->data['fleet'] = $this->mfleet->get_fleet();

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_fleet', 'ID Fleet', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('unit_id', 'Unit', 'required|callback_unit_check');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
        {
            $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('fleet_member',$this->data, true);
            $this->load->view('template/wrapper',$this->data);
        }
        else
        {

            $fleet = $this->input->post('id_fleet');
            $unit_id = $this->input->post('unit_id');

            $records = array();

            for ($i=0; $i < count($unit_id) ; $i++) { 
                $records[] = array(
                    'id_fleet' => $fleet,
                    'unit_id' => $unit_id[$i]
                    );
            }

            $query = $this->database_three->query("select
                count(id_fleet_member) as jumlah from fleet_member 
                where id_fleet = '$fleet' AND unit_id = '$unit_id'
                group by fleet_member.id_fleet");
            $ans = $query->row();

            $check = $this->database_three->query("
                select fleet.fleet_status as status, fleet_member.unit_id as unit
                from fleet, fleet_member 
                where fleet_member.unit_id = '$unit_id' AND fleet.id_fleet = '$fleet'");
            $ans2 = $query->row();


            if ($ans->jumlah > 0)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', generateErrorMessage('Data Fleet ID Sudah Digunakan'));
                redirect(site_url('fleet_member'));     
            }
            else
            {
                if ($ans2->unit == $unit_id && $ans2->status == $fleet) {

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', generateErrorMessage('Data Unit ID Sudah Digunakan'));
                    redirect(site_url('fleet_member')); 
                }
                else
                {

                    foreach ($records as $data) 
                    {
                         $query = "insert into fleet_member (id_fleet, unit_id) values ('".$data['id_fleet']."','".$data['unit_id']."')"; 
                         $this->database_three->query($query);

                    }

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', generateSuccessMessage('Data berhasil ditambah'));
                    redirect(site_url('fleet_member'));
                }

            }

        }
```

i am getting error with this code.

when i insert unit_id with same unit_id in another fleet  data cannot insert to database and show massage 'Data Unit ID Sudah Digunakan'. (its right)

when i insert unit_id with another unit_id in anohter fleet data cannot insert to database and show massage 'Data Unit ID Sudah Digunakan'. (its wrong) because it must insert to database.

can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own callback function and validate your data whether it's unique or not. Check codeigniter's user guide's form validation part. Another issue - You have not used any model, right? it's not good practice. At first, sanitize your data from controller and then Use Model for access data and manipulate data.